# Different number of results in MySQL response

Tags: mysql, where-clause

There is search form on my site and it returns different result deppending on search's words order.
Here is a part of my query proceeding after WHERE for two search words:

```
(name_ru = '".words[0]."' or name_ru like '".words[0]."%' or name_ru like '% ".words[0]."%' or name_ru like '"".words[0]."%' or brief_description_ru like '%".words[0]."%' or product_code like '%".words[0]."%' or product_code in (select product_code from ALLPRODUCTS where searchfilter like '%".words[0]."%')) or product_code in (select product_code from SC_products prd JOIN SC_product_manufacturers mnf ON prd.manufacturerID=mnf.manufacturerID where mnf.filters like '%".words[0]."%') 
AND (name_ru = '".words[1]."' or name_ru like '".words[1]."%' or name_ru like '% ".words[1]."%' or name_ru like '"".words[1]."%' or brief_description_ru like '%".words[1]."%' or product_code like '%".words[1]."%' or product_code in (select product_code from ALLPRODUCTS where searchfilter like '%".words[1]."%')) or product_code in (select product_code from SC_products prd JOIN SC_product_manufacturers mnf ON prd.manufacturerID=mnf.manufacturerID where mnf.filters like '%".words[1]."%')
```

When I changing this two words' order, the result contains different number of rows. What should I do to have everytime same result, which wouldn't depends on words order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into adding fulltext indices/using fulltext searches rather than doing the query the way you have constructed it.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html.

Fulltext searches look at the query using natural language techniques instead of specific matches.  If you are using MyISAM tables you can add fulltext indices, but most table types will allow full text searching in boolean mode.

Comment: Is there any other solution. FULLTEXT returns different row count on "apple" and "appl". LIKE function is more preferable in this situation.